# UI not updating with redux state change (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, redux

The app contains a bottom navigation bar with 5 tabs/pages, each page allowing the user to perform CRUD operations on certain lists through a viewmodel passed down to each page. My issue is that state changes are not reflected in the UI (state does actually change though, the problem is just on the UI end)
My app setup looks like this (edited to include only parts relevant to what I'm trying to solve):

**main**

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Store<AppState> store = Store<AppState>(
        appStateReducer,
        initialState: AppState.initialState()
    );
    return StoreProvider<AppState>(
      store: store,
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: "Shopping List Planner",
        theme: ThemeData.dark(),
        home: MyHomePage()
      )
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StoreConnector<AppState, AppViewModel>(
        converter: (Store<AppState> store) => AppViewModel.create(store),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AppViewModel viewModel) {
          return Scaffold(
            body: IndexedStack(
              index: viewModel.tabState.currentIndex,
              children: [
                InventoryPage(viewModel),
                BrowsePage(viewModel),
                MyRecipesPage(viewModel),
                SubmitPage(viewModel),
                ListPage(viewModel)
              ],
            ),
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
                currentIndex: viewModel.tabState.currentIndex,
                type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
                items: viewModel.buildItems(),
                onTap: viewModel.changeTab
            ),
          );
        }
    );
  }
}
```

The **AppState** contains stuff related to the bottom navigation bar index and the data (bunch of lists) the CRUD operations act on.

```
class AppState {
  final TabState tabState;
  final List<Ingredient> localInventory;
  final List<Recipe> recipes;
  final List<Recipe> userRecipes;
  final List<Ingredient> shoppingList;

  AppState({
    @required this.tabState,
    @required this.localInventory,
    @required this.recipes,
    @required this.userRecipes,
    @required this.shoppingList
  });

  AppState.initialState() : tabState = TabState.initial(),
                            localInventory = List.unmodifiable(<Ingredient>[//mock data]),
                            recipes = List.unmodifiable(<Recipe>[//mock data]),
                            userRecipes = List.unmodifiable(<Recipe>[]),
                            shoppingList = List.unmodifiable(<Ingredient>[]);

  AppState copyWith({
    TabState tabState,
    List<Ingredient> localInventory,
    List<Recipe> recipeList,
    List<Recipe> userRecipeList,
    List<Ingredient> shoppingList
  }) {
    return AppState(
      tabState: tabState ?? this.tabState,
      localInventory: localInventory ?? this.localInventory,
      recipes: recipeList ?? this.recipes,
      userRecipes: userRecipeList ?? this.userRecipes,
      shoppingList: Icons.shop ?? this.shoppingList
    );
  }
}
```

Here's the **AppViewModel** each page gets constructed with:

```
class AppViewModel {
  final TabState tabState;
  final List<Ingredient> localInventory;
  final List<Recipe> recipes;
  final List<Recipe> userRecipes;
  final List<Ingredient> shoppingList;

  final Function(Recipe) onSubmitRecipe;
  // rest of actions

  AppViewModel({
    this.tabState,
    this.changeTab,
    this.localInventory,
    this.recipes,
    this.userRecipes,
    this.shoppingList,
    this.onSubmitRecipe,
    // rest of actions
  });

  factory AppViewModel.create(Store<AppState> store) {
    _onTabChange(int index) {
      store.dispatch(ChangeTabAction(index));
    }

    _onSubmitRecipe(Recipe recipe) {
      store.dispatch(SubmitRecipeAction(recipe));
    }

    // rest of actions

    return AppViewModel(
        tabState: store.state.tabState,
        changeTab: _onTabChange,
        localInventory: store.state.localInventory,
        recipes: store.state.recipes,
        userRecipes: store.state.userRecipes,
        shoppingList: store.state.shoppingList,
        onSubmitRecipe: _onSubmitRecipe,
        // rest of actions
    );
  }

  List<BottomNavigationBarItem> buildItems() {
    return [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
        icon: Icon(Icons.home),
        label: "Inventory",
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(1, 20, 40, 100)
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          label: "Browse",
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(1, 20, 40, 100)
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          label: "My Recipes",
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(1, 20, 40, 100)
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          label: "Submit",
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(1, 20, 40, 100)
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.home),
          label: "List",
          backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(1, 20, 40, 100)
      ),
    ];
  }
}
```

Here's the reducer I wanna focus on. Its pretty much adding a `Recipe` object to the state's recipe list, taking data from a user form:

```
List<Recipe> recipeListReducer(List<Recipe> recipeList, action) {
  if(action is SubmitRecipeAction)
  {
    return []
        .. addAll(recipeList)
        .. add(Recipe(name: action.recipe.name,
            ingredients: action.recipe.ingredients,
            description: action.recipe.description));
  }
  return recipeList;
}
```

And the app state reducer:

```
AppState appStateReducer(AppState state, action) {
  return AppState(
      tabState: tabReducer(state.tabState, action),
      localInventory: ingredientReducer(state.localInventory, action),
      recipes: recipeListReducer(state.recipes, action),
      userRecipes: userRecipeListReducer(state.userRecipes, action),
      shoppingList: shoppingListReducer(state.shoppingList, action));
}
```

And finally the page that emits the `SubmitRecipeAction` action. Its a simple form that queries the fields necessary to create a new `Recipe` and calls `model.onSubmitRecipe`. I've followed the execution with the debugger and as I said, the `AppState` instance does get updated (and with it the recipe list as well), the UI does not. The same thing happens with all other actions that modify state. Not sure what exactly I'm missing. Should one of my widgets extend `ChangeNotifier`? The examples I've seen didn't need to do that so I don't know.

```
class SubmitPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title = "Submit a recipe";
  final AppViewModel model;

  SubmitPage(this.model);

  @override
  _SubmitState createState() => _SubmitState(model);
}

class _SubmitState extends State<SubmitPage> {
  final nameController = TextEditingController();
  final ingredientsController = TextEditingController();
  final descriptionController = TextEditingController();
  final AppViewModel model;

  _SubmitState(this.model);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF2E2E99),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              controller: nameController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: "Enter recipe name",
                border: OutlineInputBorder()
              ),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: ingredientsController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Enter ingredient list",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder()
              ),
            ),
            TextFormField(
              controller: descriptionController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Enter recipe description",
                  border: OutlineInputBorder()
              ),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                model.onSubmitRecipe(Recipe(name: nameController.text,
                                            ingredients: ingredientsController.text,
                                            description: descriptionController.text));
                debugPrint(nameController.text + "\n");
                debugPrint(ingredientsController.text + "\n");
                debugPrint(descriptionController.text + "\n");
              },
              child: Text("Submit recipe")
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

EDIT: sorry, I forgot to include the actual tab that should reflect the changes:

```
class BrowsePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title = "Browse recipes";
  final AppViewModel model;

  BrowsePage(this.model);

  @override
  _BrowseState createState() => _BrowseState(model);
}

class _BrowseState extends State<BrowsePage> {
  final AppViewModel model;

  _BrowseState(this.model);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: model.recipes.
        map((Recipe recipe) =>
            ListTile(
              title: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(recipe.name, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
                  Text(recipe.ingredients),
                  Text(recipe.description)
                ],
              ),
              onTap: () => { model.onAddUserRecipe(recipe) },
            )
        ).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Its just a ListView that displays the contents of the list.

Comment: What part of the UI do you expect to change? Is text not appearing?

Comment: @MichaelLee sorry, you're right, forgot to include the actual stuff that should change. Its a ListView that displays the elements of the recipe list I'm editing in `SubmitPage`. I edited the OP to include that part.

Comment: You'll definitely want to use `StatelessWidget` if you aren't calling `setState`.

Comment: After you've done that, try giving the `ListTile` a proper `key` that uniquely identifies the `recipe`. `Key(recipe.name)` will work if you can't have duplicate recipe-names.

Comment: @MichaelLee switching to `StatelessWidget` helped with one of the tabs I tried. It'll probably work with the rest as well. Silly me. Thanks for the response.